# Clipping and exporting sections of raster from multi-feature shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, data-driven-pages, slope

I have a multi feature shapefile and a slope raster and I'm trying to export images (tif, png whatever) for each feature showing the feature boundary and the slope raster contained within it with a field from the shapefile as the filename. I am dealing with a lot of features (>100,000) so efficiency is key, I tried data driven pages and it failed every time.

Comment: You said you "tried data driven pages and it failed every time" but what were the precise and detailed steps that you tried because I think Data Driven Pages is the right way to do this.

Comment: @Polygeo When I tried data driven pages I enabled it on the dateset containing the names that I wanted to be the file names of the pdf's and I made a copy of the layer and set it as the highlighted layer to show the parcel in frame and exported after setting the pdf names to the correct attribute in the data driven pages window. Out of the 27,000 parcels it exported about 80 of them with random letter number combo as the file names.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications. However, I think we’ll need more precise details of your workflow in Ofer to determine what may be astray with it.